# Allow Jetpack to access Azure VM

Tags: wordpress, azure-networking

I have a Ubuntu server on an Azure VM. It is running Wordpress and I want to give Jetpack access via port 22. However, the Azure Networking is locked down, allowing port 22 only from specific sources.

What source do I register for Jetpack?  What IP will it be coming from?

The best info I can find seems to be "Whitelist all communications between WordPress.com and Jetpack" on [this site](https://jetpack.com/support/hosting-faq/).

Comment: What's wrong with 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'd assume that the Jetpack processes are not running on my server, so using the local address would not let them reach out and connect to my server.

Comment: The Jetpack plugin is indeed a plugin running in your WordPress installation.